# How to detect the closed path in drawing application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, path, cgcontext

Am developing the drawing app, i need to fill color for each separate closed path, how to detect close path to fill color on touches like window paint app auto filler which detect close path and on touch fill selected color ?

Comment: I am also interested in an algorithm which verifies that a path in the 2D space is closed. I'd appreciate if anyone can help with this.